# Problems getting memcached stats on Windows (Membase)

Tags: memcached, membase, memcache-stats

I just installed Membase's version of Memcached (because it seems to be the only / best option to run memcached on windows) and I'm finding a strange problem.

I'm trying to make a little debug tool for myself (only for dev, not for production), and i'm trying to get the contents of memcached. However, all these commands fail:

```
stats maps
stats cachedump
stats slabs
stats items
stats sizes
```

I'm running these both from PHP and from telnet.
The only stats options that seem to work are plain "stats", and "stats reset". All the others just say "ERROR"

I'm running memcached version 1.4.4_304_g7d5a132 (according to "stats") or 1.6.4_1_ga5cbcfd (according to "version"). Not sure which one it is.

I've found references to these commands all over the Internet, and I haven't found any information about being deprecated.

Am I doing something wrong?
Are these commands removed from Membase?
Any recommendation on another version of memcached that I can simply install and will run on Windows (the simpler it is to install, the better)

Thank you!
Daniel

Answer (score 3):

Hey Daniel, the Membase server version of memcached is the easiest/best version for Windows available.  I'm happy to help you get the information you want...it might also be good to post something on our forums so all can see: http://techzone.couchbase.com/forums/

The main problem here is that we have currently implemented a proxy to allow easier cluster management.  I can get more into the details there, but the proxy will aggregate statistics across the cluster and these particular commands don't make sense to aggregate.

If you download the latest Membase version (1.7, pre-release: http://techzone.couchbase.com/products/membase/1-7-beta) you will get the following stats script that will allow you to run all of these commands:
C:\Program Files\Membase\Server\bin\mbstats :11210 raw [maps|items|slabs|sizes] [bucket_name]

I would recommend against using cachedump as it can have performance problems and isn't officially supported by the memcached server (even though it "works" in some small scales).

Perry Krug
Sr. Solutions Architect, Couchbase, Inc.